# results_ready are not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, webpack

I have typescript function

Here is code of function

```
  export class Step1{
  constructor(){
    this.begin_search();
    this.results_ready(); 
  }
private  results_ready():void{
$(function() {
  Filter.load_filter();
  let loading_more_results = false;
  let loading_more_offset = 0;
  if ((gon.search['search_type'] === 'hotel') || (gon.search['search_type'] === 'package')) {
    HotelResults.load_step_1_hotel_results();
  } else {
    AirResults.load_step_1_air_results();
  }

  if (gon.search['search_type'] === 'package') {
    for (let i of Array.from($('.step_1_air_form'))) {
      $('.tip', i).tooltipster({ contentAsHTML: true });
    }

    $('.step_1_air_form:not(.item_loaded) input[type=checkbox]').on('click', () =>
      $('.step_1_hotel_form').each(function() {
        return HotelResults.update_price_on_button_hotel($(this));
      })
    );
  }

  $('.topnav a').each(function() {
    if ($(this).target === '') { $(this).target = '_blank'; }
  });

  $('.fancybox').fancybox();

  $('.list_view').on('click', function() {
    $('.img-selected').removeClass('img-selected');
    $(this).parent().addClass('img-selected');
    $('#filter_view').val('list');
    FilterFunctions.onFilterChange();
    return false;
  });
  $('.gallery_view').on('click', function() {
    $('.img-selected').removeClass('img-selected');
    $(this).parent().addClass('img-selected');
    $('#filter_view').val('gallery');
    FilterFunctions.onFilterChange();
    return false;
  });
  $('.map_view').on('click', function() {
    $('.img-selected').removeClass('img-selected');
    $(this).parent().addClass('img-selected');
    $('#filter_view').val('map');
    FilterFunctions.onFilterChange();
    return false;
  });

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(".right_banner img").length > 0) {
      let offset;
      if ($('#header').css('position') === 'fixed') {
        offset = 75;
      } else {
        offset = 15;
      }
      if (($(".right_banner img").css('position') === 'static') && ($(window).scrollTop() > ($(".right_banner").offset().top - offset))) {
        $(".right_banner img").css("left", $(".right_banner").offset().left);
        $(".right_banner img").css("top", offset);
        $(".right_banner img").css("position", "fixed");
      }
      if (($(".right_banner img").css('position') === 'fixed') && ($(window).scrollTop() <= ($(".right_banner").offset().top - offset))) {
        $(".right_banner img").css("position", 'static');
      }
    }
    if ((($('#filter_view').length === 0) || ($('#filter_view').val() !== 'map')) && !loading_more_results && (($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) > ($(document).height() - 1250))) {
      let loading_more_results = true;
      return Itinerary.loadMoreResults();
    }
  });
  return $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(".right_banner img").css('position') === 'fixed') {
      $(".right_banner img").css("position", 'static');
      $(".right_banner img").css("left", $(".right_banner").offset().left);
      return $(".right_banner img").css("position", "fixed");
    }
  });
});


 };
}
```

I use it in webpack  pack like this

> $(document).ready(() => {
>         Translation.addDict(gon.translations);
>         Track.initialize();
>
> ```
>   new Searchfield();
>   let step1 = new Step1();
>   if (!gon.search['searched']) {
>     step1.begin_search();
>     step1.results_ready();
>
>   }
>   /*if (gon && gon.search['id'] && $('.offer_hotel_addon').length > 0) {
>     check_status();
>   }*/
> });
> ```

But when I run website I have this error at console

> results_ready is not defined

Why I get this error if it's defined in first function?

Thank's for help so much

Comment: Check your { }. The class ends before the function.

Comment: Seems like no. vs code shows that last `};' is related to class@Pam

Comment: I edited my post @Pam